# Associativity of Tensor Products

Tags: tensor-products

Here is the set up.

Let $M$ be a right $R$-module, $N$ a $(R,T)$-bimodule, and $L$ a left $T$-Module.  Then $M\bigotimes _{R} N$ is a right $T$-module and $N\bigotimes _{T} L$ is a left $R$-module.  For any fixed $l\in L$, the map $M\times N\rightarrow M\bigotimes _{R} (N\bigotimes _{T}L)$ given by $(m,n)\mapsto m\otimes (n\otimes l)$ is $R$-balanced.  So by the universal property of tensor products, there is a group homomorphism $\lambda_{l}:M\bigotimes _{R} N\rightarrow M\times N\rightarrow M\bigotimes _{R}(N\bigotimes _{T} L)$ such that  $m\otimes n\mapsto m\otimes (n\otimes l)$.

Now, I want to define a map $(M\bigotimes _{R}N)\times L\rightarrow M\bigotimes _{R}(N\bigotimes _{T} L)$ by letting $(m\otimes n,l)\mapsto m\otimes (n\otimes l)$.  By above, we know it is well defined on simple tensors $m\otimes n$, but I don't know how to interpret this so that the extension to all of $(M\bigotimes _{R}N)\times L$ makes sense.  Additively doesn't work since $(m\otimes n+m^{'}\otimes n^{'},l)=(m\otimes n,l)+(m^{'}\otimes n^{'},0)\mapsto m\otimes (n\otimes l)+m^{'}\otimes (n^{'}\otimes 0)=$ $m\otimes (n\otimes l)+ 0$.  Should I understand this to mean that $(\sum m_{i}\otimes n_{i},l)\mapsto \lambda_{l}(\sum m_{i}\otimes n_{i})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\newcommand{\ot}{\otimes}\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}\newcommand{\La}{\Lambda}\la_l:M\ot_R N\to M\ot_R(N\ot_S L)$, and so $\La:(M\ot_R N)\times L\to M\ot_R(N\ot_S L)$, with $\La(\alpha,l)=\la_l(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in(M\ot_R N)$, $l\in L$. You need to prove that
$\La$ is bilinear and $T$-balanced. This means (i) $\La(\alpha+\beta,l)=
\La(\alpha,l)+\La(\beta,l)$, (ii) $\La(\alpha,l+l')=
\La(\alpha,l)+\La(\alpha,l')$ and (iii) $\La(\alpha t,l)=\La(\alpha ,tl)$.

(i) comes from linearity of $\la_l$, (ii) follows from the case of $\alpha=m\ot n$, (iii) similarly.

Another way to approach this is to consider trilinear, $R$-balanced
and $T$-balanced maps from $M\times N\times L$ to Abelian groups, and to
show this functor is represented both by $(M\ot_R N)\ot _T L$
and $M\ot_R (N\ot_T L)$.

Comment: So I was correct when when I said " Should I understand this to mean that (∑mi⊗ni,l)↦λl(∑mi⊗ni)? "?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd yes.

Comment: Cool, that was what I got hung up on.  I know that the next thing is to show the map is T-balanced, but I need to understand the map first to do that.